# Magento 2 : How to Get all User Defined Attributes in Product Model

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, eav

I need to **get all attributes of `catalog_product` - `entity_type_id` which are user defined**. I can do this via `eav/config` analogue in Magento 1, but how can do this in Magento2  ?

Something like this query should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE entity_type_id = 4 AND is_user_defined = 1;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We should use Service Contracts Layer.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $attributeRepository;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    ......
)
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    ......
}
```

In your custom method:

```
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('is_user_defined', 1)->create();
    $attributeRepository = $this->attributeRepository->getList(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
        $searchCriteria
    );

    foreach ($attributeRepository->getItems() as $items) {
        $items->getAttributeCode();
        $items->getFrontendLabel();
    }
```

**NOTE:** For the entity type code in `getList` method, we can find in the `eav_entity_type` table.