# Magento 2 get all product attributes without product id

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

I want to **retrieve all product attributes** those are available, then convert it to name & value for my select options field. In Magento 1 I can achieve it like this:

```
public function getMagentoAttributes()
{
    $values[] = array(
        'value' => '',
        'label' => 'Pick Product Attribute'
    );

    $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->getItems();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->getFrontendLabel() != '') {
            $label = $category->getFrontendLabel();
        } else {
            $label = $category->getAttributecode();
        }

        $values[] = array(
            'value' => $category->getAttributecode(),
            'label' => $label
        );
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Is there a way in magento 2 to do the same thing?

Comment: I have used code according to "RonakChauhan" it is working fine in my block file But I am facing some issue i need help in that I am unable to filter attributes according to their visibility i.e I need the attributes whose status is set "visible => yes" in Admin...Any Help will be Appreciated... Here is my Code for getting Product Attribute's collection class ProductList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{ protected $_attributeFactory; public function __construct( \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory ){ parent::__construct($context); $this->_attrib

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
protected $_attributeFactory;

 public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    ....
}

public function <func_name>()
{
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection();

   foreach($attributeInfo as $attributes)
   {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        // You can get all fields of attribute here
   }
}
```

Here you can have whole collection of attributes, you can filter it as per your need.

Comment: how to get the attribute name and id?

Comment: using `foreach` you can get `getAttributeId()` as well as `getAttributeName()`

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: getAttributeName print blank

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($attributes);exit;` use this in foreach and check

Comment: change the getAttributeName() to getStoreLabel() and it will print the attribute name  :D

Comment: May be you can get name in `getAttributeFrontendLabel();` or `getAttributeLabel()`

Comment: use `$attributes->getData()` in `print_r();`

Comment: Why i'm getting non product attributes also like date of birth, first name, last name?

Comment: You need to filter collection as type product

Comment: @RonakChaunan when i print `getData()` it shows `entity_type_id` , and i guess for product is using `entity_type_id => 4`, is this the correct way to filter it?

Comment: yes, correct way

Comment: @Ronak Chauhan, I wish to give these attribute collection to a dropdown field . Is this possible by using toOptionArray()

Comment: yes, It's possible. @Sri

Comment: But, Can you share the  code how do I call All the attributes in the dropdown

Comment: same code you can add in toOprionArray() @Sri

Comment: It is working but failed to add filters

Comment: I need to get only the filterable attributes and visble attributes

Comment: This is not for filterable attributes,  but if you want that you can get reference from this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222102/how-to-get-filterable-attributes-from-category-in-magento-2

Answer (score 15):

Another idea is that we should try with [Service Contracts Layer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html).

**Use `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface` to get the eav attribute.**

I have an answer already here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161426/33057

For example:

```
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $attributeRepository = $this->attributeRepository->getList(
        'catalog_product',
        $searchCriteria
    );

    foreach ($attributeRepository->getItems() as $items) {
        $items->getAttributeCode();
        $items->getFrontendLabel();
    }
```

**NOTE:** For the entity type code in `getList` method, we can find in the `eav_entity_type` table.

Comment: What is 'catalog_product' as an argument in getList()??

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!