# How to get the list of all product attributes with their details

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, collection

I want to retrieve the collection of all product attributes so that I can have all the details of an attribute.

Anyone who can help me please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried all the almost all the options which I get on internet, but none of them have fulfilled my requirement. And finally I got solution, SO I am posting this answer so that it can be usefull for others also.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory;

Your Class Name
{   
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ....
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        ....
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $attr_groups = array();
        foreach ($collection as $items) {
            $attr_groups[] = $items->getData();
        }
        return $attr_groups; //This will give you the collection of all the attributes which are available in that magento instance
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve the queries similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

**1. app/code/Test/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

**2. Display product collection in phtml file**

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I don't want it on product level. I just want the list of product attributes which are available in that magento instance.

Comment: please try this link https://magento2-blog.com/magento-2-get-all-attributes-of-product/

Comment: That blog also needs product sku and I can't use anything from product.

Comment: collection of attributes https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163743/magento-2-get-all-product-attributes-without-product-id

Comment: In this, It gives all the attributes of customers, address and products.