# Magento 2: Add a Custom Import Sample File to vendor/magento/module-import-export/Files/Sample directoy

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, import, sample

I created a custom import module from two custom models and tables. The imports works fine, and without any error or problem now. But I noticed that next to **Entity Type** dropdown, appears a *"Dowload Sample File"*.

[image]

And, when I click in that (when is selected my custom entity type), the page show me a "There is no sample file for this entity." error.

So, after check the file **vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Download.php** it's look like Magento is searching the sample file in the directory:

vendor/magento/module-import-export/Files/Sample

So, the "quick" way of correcting this problem, I suppose, is to add the files of my modules in that directory. However, my question is: **is this "right"**? My logic tells me that it's not good to touch ANYTHING that's in the **vendor** folder. But then, what is the other alternative that could apply?, since it seems that with these lines:

```
fileName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filename') . '.csv';
$moduleDir = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, self::SAMPLE_FILES_MODULE);
$fileAbsolutePath = $moduleDir . '/Files/Sample/' . $fileName;
$directoryRead = $this->readFactory->create($moduleDir);
$filePath = $directoryRead->getRelativePath($fileAbsolutePath);
```

Force to search directly in that directory.

Some suggestions?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/custom-import-entity.html

Answer (score 10):

I find some solution.
Create one preference for overrides download file.

Add this code to di.xml file

```
<preference for="Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Download" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Download"/>
```

Create directory with csv file

```
NameSpace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/Files/Sample/your_csv_file.csv
```

Create Download.php file at  `NameSpace\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Import`

And put this code

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Import;

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import as ImportController;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Download as Mdownload;

class Download extends Mdownload
{
    protected $moduleReader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadFactory $readFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar $componentRegistrar,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $fileFactory,
            $resultRawFactory,
            $readFactory,
            $componentRegistrar

        );
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    }
    public function getDirectory()
    {
        $viewDir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(
            \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
            'NameSpace_ModuleName'
        );
        return $viewDir . '/adminhtml/Files/Sample/';
    }

    /**
     * Download sample file action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $fileName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filename') . '.csv';
        $moduleDir = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, self::SAMPLE_FILES_MODULE);
        $fileAbsolutePath = $moduleDir . '/Files/Sample/' . $fileName;
        $directoryRead = $this->readFactory->create($moduleDir);
        $filePath = $directoryRead->getRelativePath($fileAbsolutePath);

        if (!$directoryRead->isFile($filePath)) {

            $fileAbsolutePath = $this->getDirectory() . $fileName;
            $directoryRead = $this->readFactory->create($this->getDirectory());
            $filePath = $directoryRead->getRelativePath($fileAbsolutePath);
            if (!$directoryRead->isFile($filePath)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('There is no sample file for this entity.'));
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/import');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        }

        $fileSize = isset($directoryRead->stat($filePath)['size'])
            ? $directoryRead->stat($filePath)['size'] : null;

        $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            null,
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/octet-stream',
            $fileSize
        );
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $resultRaw->setContents($directoryRead->readFile($filePath));
        return $resultRaw;
    }
}
```

thats it, for any clarity related to this answer please mention in comment.

Comment: Thanks . This worked for me

Answer (score 7):

> For 2.3.x refer this blog [link](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-attached-download-sample-file-at-import-functionality-in-magento-2/)

Create plugin for sample download csv.

Create directory with csv file

```
NameSpace/ModuleName/Files/Sample/namespace_modulename.csv
```

Add this code to `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` file

```
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Download">
    <plugin name="Namespace_ModuleName::Import" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin\Import\Download" />
</type>
```

Create Download.php file at  `NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Import\Download.php`

And put this code

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin\Import; 

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Download
{
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
        */
    private $reader;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadFactory
        */
    private $readFactory;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
        */
    private $messageManager;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
        */
    private $resultRedirectFactory;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
        */
    private $fileFactory;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
        */
    private $resultRawFactory;
    /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
        */
    private $requestInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $requestInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $reader,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadFactory $readFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
    ) {

        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->readFactory = $readFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->requestInterface = $requestInterface;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($this->requestInterface->getParam('filename') == 'namespace_modulename_profiler') {
            $fileName = $this->requestInterface->getParam('filename') . '.csv';
            $moduleDir = $this->reader->getModuleDir('', 'Namespace_ModuleName');;
            $fileAbsolutePath = $moduleDir . '/Files/Sample/' . $fileName;
            $directoryRead = $this->readFactory->create($moduleDir);
            $filePath = $directoryRead->getRelativePath($fileAbsolutePath);

            if (!$directoryRead->isFile($filePath)) {
                /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('There is no sample file for this entity.'));
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/import');
                return $resultRedirect;
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
            }

            $fileSize = isset($directoryRead->stat($filePath)['size'])
                ? $directoryRead->stat($filePath)['size'] : null;

            $this->fileFactory->create(
                $fileName,
                null,
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/octet-stream',
                $fileSize
            );

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
            $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
            $resultRaw->setContents($directoryRead->readFile($filePath));
            return $resultRaw;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

For any clarity related to this answer please mention in comment.

Comment: Awesome @ronak Patel solution working excellent.

Comment: @NagarajuK, Ronk Patel, what should be the subject, in after excute is that Controller File are any Arguments to be passed.

Comment: Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Download is the subject

Comment: @NagarajuK thanks For your Help.

Comment: @Learing_Coder https://firebearstudio.com/blog/get-attributes-of-product-magento-2.html

Comment: @Learing_Coder https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163743/magento-2-get-all-product-attributes-without-product-id

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2.3 onwards, the sample file can be specified from custom module's di.xml file as below:

```
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import_entity" xsi:type="string">Namespace_ModuleName</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Here item name *custom_import_entity* should be similar to the entity name defined in Namespace/ModuleName/etc/export.xml file as in the below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/export.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import_entity" label="Products" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product" entityAttributeFilterType="catalog_product"/>
    <entityType entity="custom_import_entity" name="simple" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\Simple" />
    <entityType entity="custom_import_entity" name="virtual" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\Simple" />
    <fileFormat name="csv" label="CSV" model="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" />
</config>
```

Also, make sure to add the below method in your export entity model class specified in the export.xml file above.

```
/**
     * EAV entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return 'custom_import_entity';
    }
```

Sample CSV file path: Namespace/ModuleName/Files/Sample/custom_import_entity.csv

Answer (score 2):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```