# Magento2 : get all user define attributes using attribute set id on detail page

Tags: magento2, product-view, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

I got **attribute_set_id** on product detail page. like this

> [attribute_set_id] => 14

Using this i want to get all custom attribute which are set in this attribute set id.

so if you have any clue help me.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161426/33057

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, Thanks for a reply. i want to use it for grouped product detail page so how can i use it by object manager? can you please help me about this ?